# Pedals feel like they’re clicking while pedaling

Tags: pedals, clicking

I am new to cycling and have recently purchased a brand new 2020 Cannondale Caadx 105 Cyclo-cross Bicycle. I have had it for around 2-3 weeks now and I’ve started to notice a clicking feeling while I am pedaling. The clicking is not audible and typically happens twice per revolution in both pedals. The clicking is usually only felt when I am using the central gears in my rear cassette, and usually when I’m not pedaling too hard. I purchased the bike assembled from the shop, and I don’t really know what could be causing this.

Answer (score 2):

Most shop offer a free tune-up after 30 days. There is a reason for this. It can take that long for the cables to get their initial stretch. The result is the shifters need a little tweek to return to optimal performance. It is also possible that something has come loose so it worth bringing it in to the shop you purchased it from for a once over.